# Blob Trigger for Python Function App is not Firing

Tags: python, function, azure, blob, azure-triggers

I am using Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS local machine to create and publish Python Function App to Azure using CLI and Azure Functions Core Tools ([Ref](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python)). I have configured Blob Trigger and my function.json file looks like this:

```
{
"disabled": false,
"scriptFile": "__init__.py",
"bindings": [
{
  "name": "<Blob Trigger Name>",
  "type": "blobTrigger",
  "direction": "in",
  "path": "<Blob Container Name>/{name}",
  "connection": "<Connection String having storage account and key>"
},
{
  "name": "outputblob",
  "type": "blob",
  "path": "<Blob Container Name>",
  "connection": "<Connection String having storage account and key>",
  "direction": "out"
}
]
}
```

My **init**.py function looks like this.

```
def main(<Blob Trigger Name>: func.InputStream, doc: func.Out[func.Document]):
logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
             f"Name: {<Blob Trigger Name>.name}\n"
             f"Blob Size: {<Blob Trigger Name>.length} bytes")
logging.basicConfig(filename='example.log',level=logging.DEBUG)
logging.debug('This message should go to the log file')
logging.info('So should this')
logging.warning('And this, too')

# Write text to the file.
file = open("QuickStart.txt",  'w')
file.write("Hello, World!")
file.close()

# Create the BlockBlockService that is used to call the Blob service for the storage account
block_blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='<Storage Account Name>', account_key='<Storage Account Key>')
container_name='<Blob Container Name>'

# Set the permission so the blobs are public.
block_blob_service.set_container_acl(container_name, public_access=PublicAccess.Container)

# Upload the created file, use local_file_name for the blob name
block_blob_service.create_blob_from_path(container_name, 'QuickStart.txt', '')
```

The Function App is "Always On" but when I upload a blob in the storage the function is not getting triggered. Another Reference Link is this [(Ref).](https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/blob-trigger-cosmosdb-out-binding)

What's going wrong?

Thanks and regards,
Shashank

Comment: What do your Function host logs (rather than your own example.log logs) look like?

Comment: Did not run into the same problem as you, but I came across this SO post because my function wasn't getting triggered. Replacing "path": "<Blob Container Name>/" with "path": "<Blob Container Name>/{name}" fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked that the `local.settings.json` (connection strings for storage accounts) are also in the function app in Azure? They *are not* published from local machine by default.

You can configure them manually in the portal or use the *publish-local-settings* flag:

```sh
func azure functionapp publish "functionname" --publish-local-settings
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce this issue by creating a sample function app in python using Visual studio code with default template and finally deployed in Linux. It worked for me.

Here is the piece of code i have written in pyhton file.

```
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(myblob: func.InputStream):
    logging.info(f"Python blob trigger function processed blob \n"
                 f"Name: {myblob.name}\n"
                 f"Blob Size: {myblob.length} bytes")
```

and here is the function.json file from my function app.

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
      "connection": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

I am using 2.0 Azure function , python 3.6 and Azure Functions Core Tools version 2.2.70

this is the reference link i used :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-function-python

Please try to use this and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In your main def of py script you have 2nd argument of doc: func.Out[func.Document], which is for cosmos db. This should be an output stream, as its of type blob